# Slick Slider arrows over image not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position, slick.js

I am working on a slider using the slick slider library, I seem not be able to put the left and right arrow inside the picture like I am doing the texts. left arrow is not moving at all and right is only moving to the right by using margin-left.

I tried playing positions but it's not working well for me either.

this is kind of how i want it to look like 
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {



  $('.home-slick-slider').slick({

    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    arrows: true,
    dots: false,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          infinite: true,
          dots: false,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          infinite: true,
          dots: false,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          infinite: true,
          dots: false,
        }
      }
      // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
      // settings: "unslick"
      // instead of a settings object
    ]
  });
});
```

```css
.slick-slide {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.slick-prev:before {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #0a5185 !important;
  z-index: 100px;
}

.slick-next:before {
  content: "\f105";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #0a5185 !important;
  z-index: 100px;
}

.home-slick-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 70%;
  margin-right: 40%;
  color: black;
}

.home-slick-text h1 {
  color: #9FA8A6;
  text-align: right
}

.home-slick-text p {
  color: #9FA8A6 !important;
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="home-slick-slider">
      <div class="home-slider-slides">
        <div class="home-slider-content">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/73/1c/a0731cd9655f23c9596456ff800f1d85.jpg">
          <div class="home-slick-text">
            <h1>A Quality Connection</h1>
            <p>Our mission is to shape the future of health care in our community through an integrated partnership of providers and Baptist Health hospitals that work collaboratively toward common goals for improving quality, safety, efficiency and outcomes
              for our patients.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="home-slider-slides">
        <div class="home-slider-content">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/73/1c/a0731cd9655f23c9596456ff800f1d85.jpg">
          <div class="home-slick-text">
            <h1>A Quality Connection</h1>
            <p>Our mission is to shape the future of health care in our community through an integrated partnership of providers and Baptist Health hospitals that work collaboratively toward common goals for improving quality, safety, efficiency and outcomes
              for our patients.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="home-slider-slides">
        <div class="home-slider-content">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/73/1c/a0731cd9655f23c9596456ff800f1d85.jpg">
          <div class="home-slick-text">
            <h1>A Quality Connection</h1>
            <p>Our mission is to shape the future of health care in our community through an integrated partnership of providers and Baptist Health hospitals that work collaboratively toward common goals for improving quality, safety, efficiency and outcomes
              for our patients.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the `z-index` properly (it has no unit, so remove the `px`) and adjust the `left` and `right` attributes of both navigation arrows:

```
.home-slick-slider>.slick-prev {
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.home-slick-slider>.slick-next {
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This way, they will be shown above the image.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.home-slick-slider').slick({

    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    arrows: true,
    dots: false,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          infinite: true,
          dots: false,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          infinite: true,
          dots: false,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          infinite: true,
          dots: false,
        }
      }
      // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
      // settings: "unslick"
      // instead of a settings object
    ]
  });
});
```

```css
.slick-slide {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
}
.home-slick-slider>.slick-prev {
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.home-slick-slider>.slick-next {
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slick-prev:before {
  content: "\f104";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #0a5185 !important;
  z-index: 100;
}

.slick-next:before {
  content: "\f105";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #0a5185 !important;
  z-index: 100;
}

.home-slick-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 70%;
  margin-right: 40%;
  color: black;
}

.home-slick-text h1 {
  color: #9FA8A6;
  text-align: right;
}

.home-slick-text p {
  color: #9FA8A6 !important;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="home-slick-slider">
      <div class="home-slider-slides">
        <div class="home-slider-content">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/73/1c/a0731cd9655f23c9596456ff800f1d85.jpg">
          <div class="home-slick-text">
            <h1>A Quality Connection</h1>
            <p>Our mission is to shape the future of health care in our community through an integrated partnership of providers and Baptist Health hospitals that work collaboratively toward common goals for improving quality, safety, efficiency and outcomes
              for our patients.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="home-slider-slides">
        <div class="home-slider-content">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/73/1c/a0731cd9655f23c9596456ff800f1d85.jpg">
          <div class="home-slick-text">
            <h1>A Quality Connection</h1>
            <p>Our mission is to shape the future of health care in our community through an integrated partnership of providers and Baptist Health hospitals that work collaboratively toward common goals for improving quality, safety, efficiency and outcomes
              for our patients.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="home-slider-slides">
        <div class="home-slider-content">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/73/1c/a0731cd9655f23c9596456ff800f1d85.jpg">
          <div class="home-slick-text">
            <h1>A Quality Connection</h1>
            <p>Our mission is to shape the future of health care in our community through an integrated partnership of providers and Baptist Health hospitals that work collaboratively toward common goals for improving quality, safety, efficiency and outcomes
              for our patients.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```